# Unknown interpolation method array using griddata on PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, interpolation

I've already spent two days looking for the answer, but I keep having the same error and I can't understand why. Whatever I do, I keep getting the error "ValueError: Unknown interpolation method array for 1 dimensional data"

I'm trying to interpolate values to a finer meshgrid using griddata

Here's my code

```
import numpy as np

lon_ww3=array([[-10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. ],
               [ -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5],
               [ -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ],
               [ -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5]])

lat_ww3=array([[ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ],
               [ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ],
               [ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ],
               [ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ]])

Z=np.random.random_sample((4,9))*3

#Create finer mesh grid

lon_pn=[-10,-9]
lat_pn=[38,42]

lon_points=np.arange(lon_pn[0],lon_pn[1]+(300./3600),300./3600)[:-1]
lat_points=np.arange(lat_pn[0],lat_pn[1]+(300./3600),300./3600)[:-1]

LON_grid,LAT_grid=np.meshgrid(lon_points,lat_points)

from scipy.interpolate import griddata

Z_interp=griddata(lon_ww3.ravel(),lat_ww3.ravel(), Z.ravel(),LON_grid,LAT_grid)
```

I've also tried this, obviously with no success:

```
Z_interp=griddata(lon_ww3.ravel(),lat_ww3.ravel(), Z.ravel(),lon_points,lat_points)
```

And just about every possible variation I could think of... and every time I get the same error:

"ValueError: Unknown interpolation method array [LON_grid] for "nth" dimensional data"

Can anyone try to reproduce the code and help me find out what's happening?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) is wrong.

Add those lines to your code example.

```
xi = np.c_[lon_ww3.ravel(),lat_ww3.ravel()]
xx = np.c_[LON_grid.ravel(),LAT_grid.ravel()]

Z_interp=griddata(xi,Z.ravel(),xx)
```

`xi` is the `n,D` vector of your original grid points.
`xx` is the `N,D` vector of your interpolation points.

`np.c_` is column stack of each direction of the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a great example in the [documentation for griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata) 
The first argument must be a column of coordinates (not two separate values for each axis), the second is the column of values, and the third is the new grid (not two separete values). You have provided 5 arguments which is definetaly a source of the error.

And there is also some problem with you mesh creation. Here is the code which works:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

lon_ww3 = np.array([[-10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. , -10. ],
               [ -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5,  -9.5],
               [ -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ,  -9. ],
               [ -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5,  -8.5]])

lat_ww3 = np.array([[ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ],
               [ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ],
               [ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ],
               [ 38. ,  38.5,  39. ,  39.5,  40. ,  40.5,  41. ,  41.5,  42. ]])

# in fact you'd better initialise them like this
#lon_ww3, lat_ww3 = np.mgrid[-10:-9:3j,38:42:9j]

# make the column of [lon,lat] values
lon_lat = np.c_[lon_ww3.ravel(), lat_ww3.ravel()]

Z = np.random.random_sample((lon_ww3.shape))*3

# make the propper grid
LON_grid, LAT_grid = np.mgrid[-10:-9:12j,38:42:48j]

Z_interp = griddata(lon_lat, Z.ravel(), (LON_grid, LAT_grid))

# you can see what you've done like this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(Z_interp.T, extent = (-10, -8.5, 38, 42))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Leonid, It seems I didn't understand the example from the griddata documentation page. I hadn't realize the need for a two column array for it to work.