# Unknown interpolation error, in matplotlib pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Why do I get an error of the form unknown interpolation error when calling the code below ? I also include an example of the file that I am using.

Error:

```
raise ValueError("Unknown interpolation method %r for "
ValueError: Unknown interpolation method array([[23.1       , 23.44827586, 23.79655172, 24.14482759, 24.49310345,
        24.84137931, 25.18965517, 25.53793103, 25.8862069 , 26.23448276
... ]]) for 1 dimensional data
```

test.txt:

```
Lon Lat Z
32.6  -13.6   41
27.1  -16.9   43
32.7  -10.2   46
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib import rcParams

from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize


data = pd.read_csv('test.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

numcols, numrows = 30, 30
xi = np.linspace(data.Lon.min(), data.Lon.max(), numcols)
yi = np.linspace(data.Lat.min(), data.Lat.max(), numrows)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

x, y, z = data.Lon.values, data.Lat.values, data.Z.values
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi)
ax.scatter(data.Lon, data.Lat, c=data.Z, s=100,
           vmin=zi.min(), vmax=zi.max())
fig.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Check this: [Unknown interpolation method array using griddata on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065546/unknown-interpolation-method-array-using-griddata-on-python)

Comment: Im not understand one thing... Why does exactly the same example work for others? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892251/contours-with-map-overlay-on-irregular-grid-in-python

Comment: In the linked example, they use [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple): `z = griddata((xarray, yarray),  zarray, (xs, ys))`. So, here you'd need `zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi))`.  Note that `griddata` isn't limited to two-dimensional input, making tuples necessary to distinguish between its many parameters.